# Remove extra space when copying whole cell in Excel 2013 to other programs

Tags: excel, excel-2013

This isn't an issue with spaces actually in the cell, I believe. When I click into the cell and highlight then copy the contents, it pastes correctly into other programs.

If I click once and just have the cell selected, and copy/paste it into another application I get "  Data " or "Data " instead of "Data".

I have tried TRIM, CLEAN, SUBSTITUTE CHAR(160) and changing the format of the cell from general, to text, to number.. no matter what I still get extra spaces when copying the whole cell into another application.

Is this fixable? Or do I seriously just have to double click and then highlight the contents of each cell?

Wouldn't be so annoying if I could click into the cells contents and actually use CTRL+A to highlight all. Evil Excel.

Comment: You have [excel-2013] so use the [UNICODE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UNICODE-function-adb74aaa-a2a5-4dde-aff6-966e4e81f16f) on the cell. `=UNICODE(A1)` and `UNICODE(RIGHT(A1))` will tell you what you are dealing with. Report back with the results and we can probably assist further.

Comment: @Jeeped UNICODE(A1) gives me 77, UNICODE(RIGHT(A1)) gives me 81. If I copy A1's cell entirely I get "MC-2101Q " when pasted into Chrome, or "  MC-2101Q " when pasted into a chat program, if I click into the cell it claims the contents are only "MC-2101Q" though. Also might be important to note it seems to do this with no matter what excel document I'm pasting from.

Comment: OK, that's because you are copying directly from an Excel cell and not the value from the Excel formula bar. When you copy like that, you carry a terminating character. This is not an Excel thing so much as a windows clipboard interpretation of copying directly from an Excel worksheet to some other program. If you were copying two cells A1:B1, then when you pasted it there would magically be a tab between the two. If you copied A1:A2 then there would magically be a return between the two. It's a windows clipboard thing that is trying to format the copied data into the new program.

Comment: Bummer.. Thanks though!

Comment: You can write a sub procedure to put the cell contents directly on the clipboard (discarding formatting, etc) then assign that to the QAT and use that instead of Ctrl+C. A bit convoluted but if you do this enough it would be worth it.